# H12 timeout error on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, timeout

Can anyone shed some light on what's causing this timeout error on Heroku (at 2012-07-08T08:58:33+00:00)? The docs say that it's because of some long running process. I've set `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` in config/application.rb.

Specific error:

> 2012-07-08T08:58:33+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H12 (Request timeout) -> GET codicology.co.uk/ dyno=web.1 queue= wait= service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0

Full logs:

```
EmBP-2:bc Emma$ heroku restart
Restarting processes... done
EmBP-2:bc Emma$ heroku logs --tail
2012-07-08T08:47:21+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 82.69.50.215 - - [08/Jul/2012:08:47:21 +0000] "GET /assets/application.js HTTP/1.1" 200 311723 "https://codicology.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.52.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.2 Safari/534.52.7" codicology.co.uk
2012-07-08T08:47:21+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jul/2012:08:47:21 +0000] "GET /assets/application.js HTTP/1.0" 200 1311615 "https://codicology.co.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.52.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.2 Safari/534.52.7" codicology.co.uk
2012-07-08T08:51:32+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2012-07-08T08:54:05+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v145 created by emma@snowbooks.com
2012-07-08T08:54:05+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 8814b2f by emma@snowbooks.com
2012-07-08T08:54:05+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2012-07-08T08:54:06+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2012-07-08T08:54:09+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2012-07-08T08:54:09+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2012-07-08T08:54:09+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec unicorn -p 22429 -c ./config/unicorn.rb`
2012-07-08T08:54:10+00:00 app[worker.1]: [Worker(host:2046e0bf-e109-40f2-abdb-10f69d224483 pid:1)] Exiting...
2012-07-08T08:54:11+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2012-07-08T08:54:11.320616 #1]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 8 exit 0> worker=1
2012-07-08T08:54:11+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2012-07-08T08:54:11.376765 #1]  INFO -- : master complete
2012-07-08T08:54:11+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2012-07-08T08:54:11.376272 #1]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 5 exit 0> worker=0
2012-07-08T08:54:12+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2012-07-08T08:54:12.011695 #1]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
2012-07-08T08:54:12+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2012-07-08T08:54:12.011386 #1]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:22429 fd=3
2012-07-08T08:54:12+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2012-07-08T08:54:12.017917 #5]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=5
2012-07-08T08:54:12+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2012-07-08T08:54:12.019309 #1]  INFO -- : master process ready
2012-07-08T08:54:12+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2012-07-08T08:54:12.018250 #5]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
2012-07-08T08:54:12+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2012-07-08T08:54:12.016768 #1]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawning...
2012-07-08T08:54:12+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2012-07-08T08:54:12.020863 #8]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
2012-07-08T08:54:12+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2012-07-08T08:54:12.020617 #8]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawned pid=8
2012-07-08T08:54:12+00:00 app[worker.1]:   SQL (2.9ms)  UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET locked_by = null, locked_at = null WHERE (locked_by = 'host:2046e0bf-e109-40f2-abdb-10f69d224483 pid:1')
2012-07-08T08:54:12+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2012-07-08T08:54:13+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-07-08T08:54:14+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
2012-07-08T08:54:14+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to down
2012-07-08T08:54:14+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from down to starting
2012-07-08T08:54:20+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake jobs:work`
2012-07-08T08:54:20+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-07-08T08:54:28+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:6)
2012-07-08T08:54:28+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:6)
2012-07-08T08:54:28+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:6)
2012-07-08T08:54:28+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:6)
2012-07-08T08:54:33+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the New Relic Agent.
2012-07-08T08:54:33+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the New Relic Agent.
2012-07-08T08:54:33+00:00 app[web.1]: Installed New Relic Browser Monitoring middleware
2012-07-08T08:54:33+00:00 app[web.1]: Installed New Relic Browser Monitoring middleware
2012-07-08T08:54:34+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-08T08:54:34+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-08T08:54:34+00:00 app[web.1]: [DEVISE] Devise.use_salt_as_remember_token is deprecated and has no effect. Please remove it.
2012-07-08T08:54:34+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-08T08:54:34+00:00 app[web.1]: [DEVISE] Devise.use_salt_as_remember_token is deprecated and has no effect. Please remove it.
2012-07-08T08:54:34+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-08T08:54:34+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:102: warning: already initialized constant XLSX
2012-07-08T08:54:34+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:102: warning: already initialized constant PDF
2012-07-08T08:54:34+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:102: warning: already initialized constant PDF
2012-07-08T08:54:34+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:102: warning: already initialized constant XLSX
2012-07-08T08:54:34+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:102: warning: already initialized constant PDF
2012-07-08T08:54:34+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:102: warning: already initialized constant PDF
2012-07-08T08:54:41+00:00 app[worker.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:10)
2012-07-08T08:54:41+00:00 app[worker.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:10)
2012-07-08T08:54:45+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] Duplicate URL for csv with :s3_eu_url. This will clash with attachment defined in Importadvancecsv class
2012-07-08T08:54:45+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] Duplicate URL for csv with :s3_eu_url. This will clash with attachment defined in Importpaymentcsv class
2012-07-08T08:54:45+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] Duplicate URL for csv with :s3_eu_url. This will clash with attachment defined in Importpurchasecsv class
2012-07-08T08:54:45+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] Duplicate URL for csv with :s3_eu_url. This will clash with attachment defined in Importadvancecsv class
2012-07-08T08:54:45+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] Duplicate URL for csv with :s3_eu_url. This will clash with attachment defined in Importpaymentcsv class
2012-07-08T08:54:45+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] Duplicate URL for csv with :s3_eu_url. This will clash with attachment defined in Importpurchasecsv class
2012-07-08T08:54:45+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] Duplicate URL for csv with :s3_eu_url. This will clash with attachment defined in Importsalecsv class
2012-07-08T08:54:46+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] Duplicate URL for csv with :s3_eu_url. This will clash with attachment defined in Profitarchive class
2012-07-08T08:54:46+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] Duplicate URL for csv with :s3_eu_url. This will 
clash with attachment defined in Importsalecsv class
2012-07-08T08:54:46+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] Duplicate URL for csv with :s3_eu_url. This will clash with attachment defined in Profitarchive class
2012-07-08T08:54:46+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] Duplicate URL for xml with :s3_eu_url. This will clash with attachment defined in Onixarchive class
2012-07-08T08:54:47+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] Duplicate URL for xml with :s3_eu_url. This will clash with attachment defined in Onixarchive class
2012-07-08T08:54:48+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2012-07-08T08:54:48.467693 #8]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
2012-07-08T08:54:48+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2012-07-08T08:54:48.823800 #5]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
2012-07-08T08:54:48+00:00 app[worker.1]: Starting the New Relic Agent.
2012-07-08T08:54:48+00:00 app[worker.1]: New Relic Agent not running.
2012-07-08T08:54:48+00:00 app[worker.1]: [Worker(host:1eabe514-7ec9-43b0-835b-ff3bd23bc266 pid:1)] New Relic Ruby Agent Monitoring DJ worker host:1eabe514-7ec9-43b0-835b-ff3bd23bc266 pid:1
2012-07-08T08:54:48+00:00 app[worker.1]: Installed New Relic Browser Monitoring middleware
2012-07-08T08:54:49+00:00 app[worker.1]: [Worker(host:1eabe514-7ec9-43b0-835b-ff3bd23bc266 pid:1)] Starting job worker
2012-07-08T08:57:54+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2012-07-08T08:57:56+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2012-07-08T08:57:57+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2012-07-08T08:57:57.047386 #1]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 5 exit 0> worker=0
2012-07-08T08:57:57+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2012-07-08T08:57:57.047753 #1]  INFO -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 8 exit 0> worker=1
2012-07-08T08:57:57+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2012-07-08T08:57:57.047999 #1]  INFO -- : master complete
2012-07-08T08:57:57+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2012-07-08T08:57:58+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2012-07-08T08:57:58+00:00 app[worker.1]: [Worker(host:1eabe514-7ec9-43b0-835b-ff3bd23bc266 pid:1)] Exiting...
2012-07-08T08:57:59+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec unicorn -p 29766 -c ./config/unicorn.rb`
2012-07-08T08:58:01+00:00 app[worker.1]:   SQL (27.9ms)  UPDATE "delayed_jobs" SET locked_by = null, locked_at = null WHERE (locked_by = 'host:1eabe514-7ec9-43b0-835b-ff3bd23bc266 pid:1')
2012-07-08T08:58:02+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2012-07-08T08:58:02.070527 #1]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:29766 fd=3
2012-07-08T08:58:02+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2012-07-08T08:58:02.070782 #1]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
2012-07-08T08:58:02+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2012-07-08T08:58:02.074498 #1]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawning...
2012-07-08T08:58:02+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2012-07-08T08:58:02.075702 #1]  INFO -- : master process ready
2012-07-08T08:58:02+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2012-07-08T08:58:02.076732 #5]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=5
2012-07-08T08:58:02+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2012-07-08T08:58:02.076957 #5]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
2012-07-08T08:58:02+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2012-07-08T08:58:02.089022 #8]  INFO -- : worker=1 spawned pid=8
2012-07-08T08:58:02+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2012-07-08T08:58:02.089299 #8]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
2012-07-08T08:58:02+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
2012-07-08T08:58:02+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to down
2012-07-08T08:58:02+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from down to starting
2012-07-08T08:58:02+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-07-08T08:58:10+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake jobs:work`
2012-07-08T08:58:11+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-07-08T08:58:28+00:00 app[worker.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:10)
2012-07-08T08:58:28+00:00 app[worker.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/Rakefile:10)
2012-07-08T08:58:33+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H12 (Request timeout) -> GET codicology.co.uk/ dyno=web.1 queue= wait= service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0
2012-07-08T08:58:33+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 127.0.0.1 - - [08/Jul/2012:08:58:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 503 601 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.52.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.2 Safari/534.52.7" codicology.co.uk
2012-07-08T08:58:33+00:00 heroku[nginx]: 82.69.50.215 - - [08/Jul/2012:08:58:33 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 601 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.52.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.2 Safari/534.52.7" codicology.co.uk
2012-07-08T08:58:42+00:00 app[worker.1]: New Relic Agent not running.
2012-07-08T08:58:42+00:00 app[worker.1]: [Worker(host:b5fa9243-6f9b-4de4-8f64-adab767fe4b0 pid:1)] New Relic Ruby Agent Monitoring DJ worker host:b5fa9243-6f9b-4de4-8f64-adab767fe4b0 pid:1
2012-07-08T08:58:42+00:00 app[worker.1]: Starting the New Relic Agent.
2012-07-08T08:58:42+00:00 app[worker.1]: Installed New Relic Browser Monitoring middleware
2012-07-08T08:58:43+00:00 app[worker.1]: [Worker(host:b5fa9243-6f9b-4de4-8f64-adab767fe4b0 pid:1)] Starting job worker
2012-07-08T08:58:56+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:6)
2012-07-08T08:58:56+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:6)
2012-07-08T08:58:56+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:6)
2012-07-08T08:58:56+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:6)
2012-07-08T08:59:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the New Relic Agent.
2012-07-08T08:59:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Installed New Relic Browser Monitoring middleware
2012-07-08T08:59:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the New Relic Agent.
2012-07-08T08:59:02+00:00 app[web.1]: Installed New Relic Browser Monitoring middleware
2012-07-08T08:59:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-08T08:59:03+00:00 app[web.1]: [DEVISE] Devise.use_salt_as_remember_token is deprecated and has no effect. Please remove it.
2012-07-08T08:59:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-08T08:59:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-08T08:59:03+00:00 app[web.1]: [DEVISE] Devise.use_salt_as_remember_token is deprecated and has no effect. Please remove it.
2012-07-08T08:59:03+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-08T08:59:04+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:102: warning: already initialized constant XLSX
2012-07-08T08:59:04+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:102: warning: already initialized constant PDF
2012-07-08T08:59:04+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:102: warning: already initialized constant PDF
2012-07-08T08:59:04+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:102: warning: already initialized constant XLSX
2012-07-08T08:59:04+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:102: warning: already initialized constant PDF
2012-07-08T08:59:04+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:102: warning: already initialized constant PDF
2012-07-08T08:59:22+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] Duplicate URL for csv with :s3_eu_url. This will clash with attachment defined in Importadvancecsv class
2012-07-08T08:59:22+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] Duplicate URL for csv with :s3_eu_url. This will clash with attachment defined in Importpaymentcsv class
2012-07-08T08:59:22+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] Duplicate URL for csv with :s3_eu_url. This will clash with attachment defined in Importpurchasecsv class
2012-07-08T08:59:22+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] Duplicate URL for csv with :s3_eu_url. This will clash with attachment defined in Importsalecsv class
2012-07-08T08:59:22+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] Duplicate URL for csv with :s3_eu_url. This will clash with attachment defined in Profitarchive class
2012-07-08T08:59:23+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] Duplicate URL for csv with :s3_eu_url. This will clash with attachment defined in Importadvancecsv class
2012-07-08T08:59:23+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] Duplicate URL for csv with :s3_eu_url. This will clash with attachment defined in Importpaymentcsv class
2012-07-08T08:59:23+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] Duplicate URL for csv with :s3_eu_url. This will clash with attachment defined in Importpurchasecsv class
2012-07-08T08:59:23+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] Duplicate URL for csv with :s3_eu_url. This will clash with attachment defined in Importsalecsv class
2012-07-08T08:59:23+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] Duplicate URL for csv with :s3_eu_url. This will clash with attachment defined in Profitarchive class
2012-07-08T08:59:23+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] Duplicate URL for xml with :s3_eu_url. This will clash with attachment defined in Onixarchive class
2012-07-08T08:59:24+00:00 app[web.1]: [paperclip] Duplicate URL for xml with :s3_eu_url. This will clash with attachment defined in Onixarchive class
2012-07-08T08:59:25+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2012-07-08T08:59:25.555052 #5]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
2012-07-08T08:59:25+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-08T08:59:25+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-07-08T08:59:25+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 82.69.50.215 at 2012-07-08 08:59:25 +0000
2012-07-08T08:59:26+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2012-07-08T08:59:26+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2012-07-08T08:59:26.043501 #8]  INFO -- : worker=1 ready
2012-07-08T08:59:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.haml within layouts/application (5.7ms)
2012-07-08T08:59:26+00:00 app[web.1]:    (1.1ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "delayed_jobs" 
2012-07-08T08:59:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (4.2ms)
2012-07-08T08:59:26+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.haml (1.4ms)
2012-07-08T08:59:26+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 326ms (Views: 258.4ms | ActiveRecord: 65.2ms)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> heroku[router]: Error H12 (Request timeout) -> GET codicology.co.uk/ dyno=web.1 queue= wait= service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0

Are you loading something from `codicology.co.uk` during the deployment of your app? e.g. loading a custom buildpack that is hosted there?

If I visit codicology.co.uk I get a certificate error. Perhaps whatever process or request you're running from Heroku is getting a certificate error also which prevents it from properly connecting, or perhaps it decides to drop the connection because of the error.

If you can give us a bit more information about what you're trying to do or what codicology.co.uk is used for (do you own it?) perhaps we can help more.

Comment: Hi - nothing fancy loading. Yes, I own codicology.co.uk which is a staging site for my main production app, hence the lack of a bought ssl certificate. The h12 error seems to have stopped, but I have no idea why... thanks for your help, anyway.

Comment: @snowangel Glad to hear it working! Though I would rather help you fix your problem than simply earn the rep ;) Did you make any changes?